# How can I repair older Hunter 12-inch popup sprinklers that have worn out riser splines? They rotate to a different direction each time they run

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation

I have about 3-dozen of these worn out sprinklers and in every case the internal splines that keep the riser from rotating are worn out or stripped. Sprinkler replacement is difficult as they all utilize the horizontal side water supply. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: did you open one

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer yet?. There may be a repair kit. (Or they may tell you to fog up and replace the sprinkler head exactly the way it was originally installed; I don't know.)

Comment: I assume you have taken the insides out? I have seen the insides replaced twice, but never seen problems with the splines.